# How to *write* a C++17 algorithm with a parallel execution policy

Tags: parallel-processing, c++17, tbb

I want to write a C++17 parallel execution algorithm, but I'm having some trouble. Let's start with the code:

```cpp
#if __has_include(<execution>)
#include <execution>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#endif

template<class RandomAccessIterator>
inline auto mean(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last)
{
    auto it = first;
    auto mu = *first;
    decltype(mu) i = 2;
    while(++it != last)
    {
        mu += (*it - mu)/i;
        i += 1;
    }
    return mu;
}


#if __has_include(<execution>)
template<class ExecutionPolicy, class RandomAccessIterator>
inline auto mean(ExecutionPolicy&& exec_pol, RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last) {
    using Real = typename std::iterator_traits<RandomAccessIterator>::value_type;
    //static_assert(std::is_execution_policy_v<ExecutionPolicy>, "First argument must be an execution policy.");
    if (exec_pol == std::execution::par) {
        size_t elems = std::distance(first, last);
        if (elems*sizeof(Real) < /*guestimate*/ 4096) {
            return mean(first, last);
        }

        unsigned threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
        if (threads == 0) {
            threads = 2;
        }
        std::vector<std::future<Real>> futures;
        size_t elems_per_thread = elems/threads;
        auto it = first;
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < threads -1; ++i) {

            futures.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, &mean<RandomAccessIterator>, it, it + elems_per_thread));
            it += elems_per_thread;
        }
        futures.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, &mean<RandomAccessIterator>, it, last));

        Real mu = 0;
        for (auto fut : futures) {
            mu += fut.get();
        }
        mu /= threads;
        return mu;
    }
    else { // should have else-if for various types of execution policies, but let's save that for later.
         return mean(first, last);
    }
}
#endif
```

Ok, so questions:

- I started out by passing the `ExecutionPolicy` argument by `const &`. The `static_assert` passed, but then I got hung a compile error on the `if (exec_pol == std::execution::par)`, namely:

```
 error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘const __pstl::execution::v1::parallel_policy’ and ‘const __pstl::execution::v1::parallel_policy’)
  117 |     if (exec_pol == std::execution::par) {
      |         ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Then I looked at `/usr/include/c++/9/pstl/algorithm_impl.h`, and in it, they are passing the `ExecutionPolicy` around by move and forwarding it various places, so I guess I should to. But that didn't fix anything, so I looked at `/usr/include/c++/9/pstl/parallel_backend_tbb.h`. And in that file, they don't even check what the parallel execution policy is! For example, as few lines from the aforementioned file:

```
//! Evaluation of brick f[i,j) for each subrange [i,j) of [first,last)
// wrapper over tbb::parallel_for
template <class _ExecutionPolicy, class _Index, class _Fp>
void
__parallel_for(_ExecutionPolicy&&, _Index __first, _Index __last, _Fp __f)
{
    tbb::this_task_arena::isolate([=]() {
        tbb::parallel_for(tbb::blocked_range<_Index>(__first, __last), __parallel_for_body<_Index, _Fp>(__f));
    });
}
```

So have I fundamentally misunderstood how to write a parallel algorithm using C++17 parallel execution policies? If not, how do I check the execution policy and use it correctly?

Comment: Is a mean what you really want? Then this single line:  `auto mean = std::reduce(std::execution::par, v.begin(), v.end()) / v.size();`  will do what you want.

Using the std algorithms for the various execution policies can and will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy: I don't care about mean at all. This is just an easy example for everyone to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take `ExecutionPolicy&& exec_pol` by value: `ExecutionPolicy exec_pol`.  It is a tag.  Taking by forwarding reference just confuses things.

Either test for type, or tag dispatch:

```
if constexpr(std::is_same_v<ExecutionPolicy,
                        std::execution::parallel_policy>)
```

as @Davis answer implies.

If you don't want to take by value (and you should take by value), you can use either `std::decay_t` or `std::remove_ref_t< std::remove_cv_t< ExecutionPolicy > >` to strip off the cv/ref that perfect forwarding stores in the type.

But again, don't do that.

Answer (score 4):

You need to examine the **type** of the policy, perhaps with something like

```
if constexpr(std::is_same_v
               <std::remove_reference_t<ExecutionPolicy>,
                std::execution::parallel_policy>)
```

Comment: Wait, then why is it passed as a function argument and not a template argument?

Comment: (Obviously there is a template parameter as well.)  The normal parameter allows stateful policies (but the standard three are not).

Comment: Ok, so I guess there will be more functionality to this added over time . . ., say C++20/C++23?

Comment: That is exactly "tag dispatch" pattern. you can restrict policy by overload.

Comment: @user14717: C++20 doesn’t add anything here, but vendor extensions might.

Comment: @DavisHerring: Just tried your solution. None of `std::execution::par`, `std::execution::par_unseq`, `std::execution::seq` causes the `std::is_same_v<>` to evaluate to true, using g++-9.

Comment: @user14717: That’s because of the forwarding reference; edited.  (I did say “something like”!)